# R - ggmap - calculate shortest distance between cities via geocoding

Tags: r, list, dataframe, geocoding, ggmap

I have a list of cities and related information that I've placed in a dataframe, like so:

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggmap)
library(Imap)

cities <- c("washington, dc", "wilmington, de", "amarillo, tx", 
            "denver, co", "needham, ma", "philadelphia, pa", 
            "doylestown, pa", "galveston, tx", "tuscaloosa, al", 
            "hollywood, fl"
            )

id <- c(156952, 154222, 785695, 154423, 971453, 149888, 1356987,
        178946, 169944, 136421)

month <- c(201811, 201811, 201912, 201912, 202005, 202005, 
           202005, 202106, 202106, 202106 )

category<- c("home", "work", "home", "home", "home", "work",
             "cell", "home", "work", "cell")

places <- data.frame(cities, id, category, month)
```

Using the `Imap` and `ggmap` packages, I can retrieve the longitude and latitudes for each city:

```
lat <- geocode(location = places$cities, source = "google")$lat
lon <- geocode(location = places$cities, source = "google")$lon

places <- cbind(places, lat, lon)
```

What I would like to do is the following:

1. Calculate the distance between each city by month and category
2. return the second shortest distance and the corresponding city and id in separate columns in `places`

I wrote a `for` loop to calculate the distances:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(places)) {




dist_list[[i]] <- gdist(lon.1 = places$lon[i], 
                          lat.1 = places$lat[i], 
                          lon.2 = places$lon, 
                          lat.2 = places$lat,
                          units="miles")
  
}
```

Which produces the following data:

```
dput(dist_list)
list(c(0, 98.3464717885451, 1386.25425677199, 1489.87718040776, 
383.083760289456, 123.232894969413, 140.284537078237, 1209.23510542932, 
706.670452283757, 906.79542720295), c(98.4762434610638, 0, 1472.06660056474, 
1560.93398322985, 285.23618862797, 24.9195071209828, 44.8853561530985, 
1308.60741637919, 805.755084908157, 983.102810248198), c(1389.07354011351, 
1472.06660056474, 0, 356.573530670257, 1712.29111612461, 1493.39302974566, 
1497.2125164277, 579.329313217289, 827.577713357261, 1434.82691622332
), c(1492.80130415651, 1560.93398322985, 356.573530670257, 0, 
1761.3773163288, 1578.71125031146, 1576.80713231756, 923.725006795209, 
1067.04809350934, 1717.32991551111), c(383.551997010915, 285.23618862797, 
1712.29111612461, 1761.3773163288, 0, 260.382178510916, 243.947043197789, 
1588.85470703957, 1088.38640303169, 1230.47219244291), c(123.395655314093, 
24.9195071209827, 1493.39302974566, 1578.71125031146, 260.382178510916, 
0, 24.7382114555287, 1333.29925285915, 830.581742827321, 1002.94777739349
), c(140.431447025301, 44.8853561530986, 1497.2125164277, 1576.80713231756, 
243.947043197789, 24.7382114555285, 0, 1346.44527983873, 844.827513981938, 
1026.98263808807), c(1211.16392416136, 1308.60741637919, 579.329313217289, 
923.725006795209, 1588.85470703957, 1333.29925285915, 1346.44527983873, 
0, 505.292529136012, 925.512554201542), c(707.73957320737, 805.755084908157, 
827.577713357261, 1067.04809350934, 1088.38640303169, 830.581742827321, 
844.827513981938, 505.292529136012, 0, 666.837848781548), c(906.880841903584, 
983.102810248198, 1434.82691622332, 1717.32991551111, 1230.47219244291, 
1002.94777739349, 1026.98263808807, 925.512554201542, 666.837848781548, 
0))
```

The desired result would look like this (first row):

```
cities          id         category  month      lat        lon   min.dist  closest city  closest city id  
washington, dc  156952     home      201811 38.90719  -77.03687   98.34647  wilmington, de  154222
```

And via the `nth` function in `Rfast` I can get the second smallest distance

`nth(dist_list[[1]], 2)`

The problem I have is I don't know how to connect the info from the list to the df `places`.  Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# get min distance:
min_d <- sapply(dist_list, function(x) sort(x)[2])
places$min_dist <- min_d
# index:
i <- sapply(dist_list, function(x) which(sort(x)[2] == x))
# add name:
places$min_name <- places$cities[i]
```

### With grouping:

```
# prepare dist matrix outside loop
m <- t(as.data.frame(dist_list))
row.names(m) <- NULL
diag(m) <- NA

# create grouping variable:
gv <- as.integer(factor(places$month)) # or:
# gv <- as.integer(factor(paste(places$month, places$category)))

# set distance to NA if not in relevant group:
i <- sapply(gv, function(x) gv == x)
m[!i] <- NA

l <- sapply(as.data.frame(t(m)), function(x) {
  if (all(is.na(x))) return(list(NA, NA))
  mv <- min(x, na.rm = T)
  i <- which(x == mv)
  list(mv, i)
})
l
places <- cbind(places, min_dist = unlist(l[1, ]), min_nr = unlist(l[2, ]))

places$min_name <- places$cities[places$min_nr] # add name
places$min_id <- places$id[places$min_nr] # add id
places
```

result:

```
              cities      id category  month  min_dist min_nr         min_name  min_id
V1    washington, dc  156952     home 201811  98.34647      2   wilmington, de  154222
V2    wilmington, de  154222     work 201811  98.47624      1   washington, dc  156952
V3      amarillo, tx  785695     home 201912 356.57353      4       denver, co  154423
V4        denver, co  154423     home 201912 356.57353      3     amarillo, tx  785695
V5       needham, ma  971453     home 202005 243.94704      7   doylestown, pa 1356987
V6  philadelphia, pa  149888     work 202005  24.73821      7   doylestown, pa 1356987
V7    doylestown, pa 1356987     cell 202005  24.73821      6 philadelphia, pa  149888
V8     galveston, tx  178946     home 202106 505.29253      9   tuscaloosa, al  169944
V9    tuscaloosa, al  169944     work 202106 505.29253      8    galveston, tx  178946
V10    hollywood, fl  136421     cell 202106 666.83785      9   tuscaloosa, al  169944
```

Comment: this works pretty well but what if i need to calculate the distance using a by variable?

Comment: @jvalenti what do you mean? it is not clear... by groups?  for example calculate closes city where month is equal?

Comment: @minem...for example, `by` `month` and `id`....also the `id` of the closest city should be returned as well in `places`

Comment: one more question:  what if `dist_list` and `places` had different lengths?  As of now, `i <- sapply(dist_list, function(x) which(sort(x)[2] == x))` doesn't work if the lengths are of different.

Comment: @jvalenti in your question you specified that you create `dist_list` from `places`, so they should relate one to one. If you are using some subset of one or other then you need to subset everything...

Comment: ok thanks, I realized I wanted to take the `lat <- geocode(location = unique(places$cities), source = "google")$lat`

Answer (score 3):

## Update

Assuming we group by `month` only, we can try the code below

```
f <- function(df) {
    r <- list()
    for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
        x <- c()
        for (j in 1:nrow(df)) {
            x <- append(
                x,
                with(df, gdist(lat[i], lon[i], lat[j], lon[j], units = "miles"))
            )
        }
        x <- replace(x, x == 0, Inf)
        idx <- which.min(x)
        r[[i]] <- data.frame(
            min.dist = min(x),
            closest_city = df$cities[idx],
            closest_city_id = df$id[idx]
        )
    }
    do.call(rbind, r)
}

places %>%
    group_by(month) %>%
    do(cbind(., f(.))) %>%
    ungroup()
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 10 x 9
   cities               id category  month   lat    lon min.dist closest_city   
   <chr>             <int> <chr>     <int> <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>
 1 washington, dc   156952 home     201811  38.9  -77.0   104.   wilmington, de
 2 wilmington, de   154222 work     201811  39.7  -75.5   104.   washington, dc
 3 amarillo, tx     785695 home     201912  35.2 -102.    232.   denver, co
 4 denver, co       154423 home     201912  39.8 -105.    232.   amarillo, tx
 5 needham, ma      971453 home     202005  42.3  -71.2   273.   doylestown, pa
 6 philadelphia, ~  149888 work     202005  40.0  -75.2     6.81 doylestown, pa
 7 doylestown, pa  1356987 cell     202005  40.3  -75.1     6.81 philadelphia, ~
 8 galveston, tx    178946 home     202106  29.2  -94.9 11405.   hollywood, fl
 9 tuscaloosa, al   169944 work     202106  33.2  -87.6   517.   hollywood, fl
10 hollywood, fl    136421 cell     202106  26.0  -80.1   517.   tuscaloosa, al
# ... with 1 more variable: closest_city_id <int>
```

---

Based on your obtained `dist_list`, we can try the code below

```
closest <- do.call(
    rbind,
    lapply(
        dist_list,
        function(x) {
            x <- replace(x, x == 0, Inf)
            idx <- which.min(x)
            with(
                places,
                data.frame(
                    min.dist = min(x),
                    closest_city = cities[idx],
                    closest_city_id = id[idx]
                )
            )
        }
    )
)
```

which gives

```
    min.dist     closest_city closest_city_id
1   98.34647   wilmington, de          154222
2   24.91951 philadelphia, pa          149888
3  356.57353       denver, co          154423
4  356.57353     amarillo, tx          785695
5  243.94704   doylestown, pa         1356987
6   24.73821   doylestown, pa         1356987
7   24.73821 philadelphia, pa          149888
8  505.29253   tuscaloosa, al          169944
9  505.29253    galveston, tx          178946
10 666.83785   tuscaloosa, al          169944
```

Also, if you want to append the above data frame to your existing `places`, you can use

```
places <- cbind(places, closest)
```

Comment: this looks great...what if i need to make the calc by `id, month`?

Comment: @jvalenti see my udpate

Comment: If `month` is the grouping variable, `washington, dc` should be the second row.  Also, can you explain what is `min_nr`?

Comment: @jvalenti No, I don't have `min_nr`

Answer (score 3):

### use `sf::st_distance()`

Given that you're working with spatial data, I advise an approach based on spatial libraries like `{sf}`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidygeocoder)
library(sf)

# clean location, geocode, and convert to sf object
places <- places %>% 
  separate(cities, into = c("city", "state"), sep = ", ") %>% 
  geocode(city = city, state = state) %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("long", "lat"), crs = 4269)

# sanity check
mapview::mapview(places)
```

[image]

```
# calculate distances between point pairs with st_distance()
compute_close_city <- function(i){
  # compute distances btwn a point and its neighbors (excluding itself)
  distances = st_distance(places[i, ], places[-i, ])
  # index of the nearest neighbor
  j = which.min(distances)
  
  # organize and return the result
  result <- tibble(
    close_city   = places$city[-i][j],  # closest city
    close_state  = places$state[-i][j], # closest state
    close_dist_m = distances[j]         # distance in meters
  )
  
  return(result)
}

# calculate close cities and distances, bind results into dataframe
close_df <- map_df(1:nrow(places), ~compute_close_city(.x))

# bind the result to the places data frame
places <- bind_cols(places, close_df)

# view the result and verify it works
select(places, city, close_city, close_dist_m)
```

Returns:

```
Simple feature collection with 10 features and 3 fields
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -104.9849 ymin: 26.0112 xmax: -75.13046 ymax: 40.31004
Geodetic CRS:  NAD83
# A tibble: 10 x 4
   city         close_city   close_dist_m             geometry
   <chr>        <chr>                 [m]          <POINT [°]>
 1 washington   wilmington      159476.85 (-77.03656 38.89499)
 2 wilmington   philadelphia     40022.81 (-75.54659 39.74595)
 3 amarillo     denver          574956.04 (-101.8338 35.20722)
 4 denver       amarillo        574956.04 (-104.9849 39.73924)
 5 needham      tuscaloosa      153463.74 (-88.33309 31.98683)
 6 philadelphia doylestown       39775.87 (-75.16353 39.95272)
 7 doylestown   philadelphia     39775.87 (-75.13046 40.31004)
 8 galveston    needham         687140.47 (-94.79459 29.29933)
 9 tuscaloosa   needham         153463.74 (-87.56753 33.20956)
10 hollywood    needham        1035934.60  (-80.14949 26.0112)
```

Comment: this is pretty elegant...but entries for rows 4, 8-10 aren't right.

Comment: I think the problem here is the distances are not calculated by `month`, `category`.